# Найти внутри objecta params

Tags: javascript

Извините за дурацкий вопрос
но как можно добраться до params?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы знаете структуру данных, то добраться можно напрямую, например:

```
mydata.elements[0].params.coup
```

А если структуру не знаете и вам надо допустим найти все params в некотором объекте, то придётся пройтись по всем его ключам (если объект) и элементам массива (если массив) и искать по названию ключа `params`

```
function findByKey(data, key, results) {
    if (Array.isArray(data) == true) {
        // если данные - массив, то пройтись по всем элементам
        for (const element of data) {
            findByKey(element, key, results);
        }
    }
    else if (typeof data == 'object') {
        // если данные - объект, то пройтись по всем ключам
        const keys = Object.keys(data);
        
        for (const element of keys) {
            // если ключ соответствует искомому - занести в массив результатов
            if (key == element) {
                results.push(data[element]);
            }
            
            findByKey(data[element], key, results);
        }       
    }
}


let mydata = [
    {
        params: 10
    },
    {
        elements: [
            {
                params: 11,
            },
            {           
                objects: {
                    params: 12
                }
            }
        ]
    }
];

results = [];
findByKey(mydata, "params", results);

console.log(results);
```